# Virtualenv All Messed Up - Segmentation Fault: 11

Tags: python, virtualenv

I'm a little worried right now I may have majorly messed things up for myself... but here's what happened:

After upgrading to OSX Yosemite I was having issues with my Python installation, so I reinstalled using `brew python` and `brew python3`. My previous installations were not installed through homebrew. After this, I began having problems with python packages I had previously installed, namely pip, virtualenv, and virtualenvwrapper. I messed around with things for a while, deleted the pre-existing Python framework in /Library and uninstalled and reinstalled the three packages to get them all working with the new, homebrewed python I'm running.

Now, when I open a virtualenv that I had created prior to this whole ordeal and try to run any commands from any python package (like `pip freeze` or `./manage.py runserver`), I get `Segmentation Fault: 11`

Does anyone know why I am getting this error or how I can fix it?

**EDIT** Also while the virtualenv experts are here... is there a way that I can make my python version for virtualenv default to python3?

Comment: Recreate the venv? Or is that not an option

Comment: I suppose that's what I'll have to do. Do you know how to make the default python for virtualenv python3?

Comment: Rather I'll just use the relatively new pyvenv-3.4

Comment: Did that comment just make my answer obsolete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many things could be the cause of the error, I'm not even going to try and guess.

Because you have been messing around a lot, I'd say the easiest and maybe best option would be to just recreate your virtualenv

> is there a way that I can make my python version for virtualenv
>   default to python3?

Default for all venvs, I don't know. But you can make a new virtualenv with python 3.x with this command

```
$ virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3 virtualenv_name
```